# Grab data from Google Sheets and create emails in Gmail with recipients, subject and body based on it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have a sheet with data that must serve as input parameters to emails in gmail.
[Here is an example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ncY03PRbrl4Rs3BdIqwoBvKY47EPCmVyPAHNVWQAmFw/edit#gid=0), but basically this is it:

[image]

So, the email must be copied to the people in Column A ("Emails"), it should have a defined subject, which is on B2 and a defined body text in C2.

Is there a way to create an Appscript that connects Google Sheets to Gmail and creates an email like this below? Could you suggest a script for that based in the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ncY03PRbrl4Rs3BdIqwoBvKY47EPCmVyPAHNVWQAmFw/edit#gid=0)?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Check out what can be done using google apps scripts.

Comment: @a-burge can you suggest a script for that?

Comment: I'd say try googling it. First hit provides a video and then there's plenty of other results that should help you get on your way. https://www.google.com/search?q=send+email+from+google+sheet+%2B+google+apps+script&oq=send+email+from+google+sheet+%2B+google+apps+script&aqs=chrome..69i57.8640j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example code that might work for you this would take the rows of the emails and send different emails:

```js
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
var subject = sheet1.getRange(i,2).getValue();
var message = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

}
```

By inserting a Google Drawing:

You add a button via the Insert > Drawing menu.

You edit the drawing and after finishing it, you click on the three dots and assign a script, you just need to write the function name, in my case it is the

> sendEmail

You can take a look at the [Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dStVy1JojfHa75s1ciHBkMEb-u0vIjI0EOSf2uO4cvw/edit?usp=sharing) and how it looks, very similar to yours.

Also if you are looking only to send a template email to all the emails from column A, you can use this one:

```js
function sendEmail() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet4');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('somesheet');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();;
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,1).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

}
```

Note:

-In order to use the template example, I used two workbooks or worksheets.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var emailAddress = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().join();
  var subject = sh.getRange('B2').getValue();
  var message = sh.getRange('C2').getValue();
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

instead of a button, you can add custom menu

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' send emails', 'sendEmail')
    .addToUi();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send email using App Script it only needs one line

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

You have all these required information in your sheets that you can pull.

You can use the code below. Just change the Spreadsheet URL.
This works by looping through your rows starting from row 2 up to what row contains data to get the email address, subject, and message.

```
function sendMultipleEmails(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('<your_SpreadSheetURL>');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  var n = sheet.getLastRow();
  //loop through rows with data
  for (i = 2; i < n+1; i++){
    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
    var subject = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var message = sheet.getRange(i,3).getValue();
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,message);
  }
};
```

Just assign this function to your button and it should work.

- Refer to this link for more information on sending Emails from SpreadSheet using App Script:
  https://productivityspot.com/automatically-send-emails-from-google-sheets/
- On how you can add function to button:
  https://spreadsheet.dev/buttons-in-google-sheets